# Como executar uma paginação com PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em `PHP` mas acabei de me iniciar em `PDO` e não tenho a mínima ideia de como fazer uma paginação usando o mesmo.

Eu consegui montar uma pequena `query` com exemplo das informações a printar e gostaria de uma ajuda para terminar a tarefa de paginação do conteúdo.

```
<?php
    # Este script é responsável por puxar do banco de dados que
    # serão solicitados através da busca pelo tipo de imóvel
    # desejado.
    require("configs/conexao.php");

    $busca      = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM imovel LIMIT 60");
    $busca      ->execute();
?>

<?php

foreach($busca as $linhas) { ?>

    <div class="dados">
        Código: <?=$linhas['IMO_CODIGO']?>
        Bairro: <?=$linhas['BAIRRO']?>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Consegue fazer sem o PDO? A idéia é a mesma, você só vai parametrizar o `LIMIT`.

Comment: Não sei como misturar duas tecnologias, `mysql` e `pdo` e ainda tem aquele história de que a qualquer momento o `PHP` vai extinguir as instruções `mysql_` e ainda por cima sou iniciante, então não sei o que fazer.

Comment: Bem você não irá misturar `mysql_` com `pdo`. Reaproveite a lógica que você usaria.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Este é um script completo de `paginação em PDO`. Fiquem a vontade!!!

Está aqui: http://pastebin.com/CkcwxdDi

```
<?php

# inclui o arquivo config(arquivo de conexão com o banco de dados)
require("configs/conexao.php");

# Limita o número de registros a serem mostrados por página
$limite = 75;

# Se pg não existe atribui 1 a variável pg
$pg = (isset($_GET['pg'])) ? (int)$_GET['pg'] : 1;

# Atribui a variável inicio o inicio de onde os registros vão ser
# mostrados por página, exemplo 0 à 10, 11 à 20 e assim por diante
$inicio = ($pg * $limite) - $limite;

# seleciona os registros do banco de dados pelo inicio e limitando pelo limite da variável limite
$sql = "SELECT * FROM imovel ORDER BY IMO_CODIGO DESC LIMIT ".$inicio. ", ". $limite;

try {

        $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();

        } catch (PDOexception $error_sql){

                echo 'Erro ao retornar os Dados.'.$error_sql->getMessage();

}

while($linha = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>

                <li>
                    <h3><?=$linha['BAIRRO']?></h3>
                    <a href="<?php bloginfo("url"); ?>/imovel?cod_consulta=<?=$linha['IMO_CODIGO']?>">
                        <?php if($semfoto == 'null') { ?>
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/logo.jpg" />
                        <?php } else { ?>
                                <img src="<?=$linha['FOTO_PRINCIPAL']?>" />
                        <?php } ?>    
                    </a>                            
                    <div class="area"><?=round($linha['AREA_TOTAL'])?>m²</div>
                    <div class="vaga">2</div>
                    <div class="dorm"><?=$linha['DORMITORIO']?></div>
                        <?php if($linha['CATEGORIA'] == 'CASA EM CONDOMINIO'){
                                $emcondominio = explode(" ", $linha['CATEGORIA']);
                                $nomemodificado = $emcondominio[1] ." ". $emcondominio[2];
                                echo "<span class='categoria'>$nomemodificado</span>";
                        } else { ?>
                    <span class="categoria"><?=$linha['CATEGORIA']?></span>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <span class="valor"><?=money_format('%n', $linha['VLR_VENDA']) ?></span>
                </li>

<?php }

# seleciona o total de registros  
$sql_Total = 'SELECT IMO_CODIGO FROM imovel';

try {

        $query_Total = $pdo->prepare($sql_Total);
        $query_Total->execute();

        $query_result = $query_Total->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        # conta quantos registros tem no banco de dados
        $query_count =  $query_Total->rowCount(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        # calcula o total de paginas a serem exibidas
        $qtdPag = ceil($query_count/$limite);

        } catch (PDOexception $error_Total){

                echo 'Erro ao retornar os Dados. '.$error_Total->getMessage();

        }

        # Cria os links para navegação das paginas
        echo "<div class='relax h30'></div>";
        # echo '<a href="busca?pg=1">PRIMEIRA PÁGINA</a>&nbsp;';
        echo '<ul id="paginacao">';
    echo '<li><a class="anterior" href="busca?pg=1">Anterior</a></li>';

        if($qtdPag > 1 && $pg <= $qtdPag){

                for($i = 1; $i <= $qtdPag; $i++){

                        if($i == $pg){

                                echo "<li><a class='ativo'>".$i."</a></li>";

                        } else {

                                echo "<li><a href='busca?pg=$i'>".$i."</a></li>";

                        }

                }

        }

        echo "<li><a class='proxima' href='busca?pg=$qtdPag'>Próxima</a></li>";

?>
```