# Como limitar a quantidade de páginas mostradas numa paginação?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, paginação

Com **[esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34795/como-executar-uma-pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-pdo)** que já tem solução, eu consegui como resultado uma `paginação com PDO` mas tenho mais um problema que será possivelmente alvo de uma recompensa semana que vem.

Como podem ver na imagem abaixo, eu tenho esta paginação com **+/-** 1000 imóveis que dividido por grupos de 12 por página, vai me retornar um total de **+/-** 90 páginas que serão escritas em forma de paginação fazendo com que eu tenha umas 3 ou 4 linhas mostrando números que vão perder o sentido e irá ficar monstruosamente horrível.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso limitar a quantidade de páginas a serem mostradas reaproveitando o código mostrado dentro da então **[respondida pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34795/como-executar-uma-pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-pdo)** presente neste mesmo? Caso achem necessário, replicarei o código aqui dentro que se encontra **[aqui](http://pastebin.com/CkcwxdDi)**.

Comment: Não entendi... o que você quer limitar? O numero das páginas linkadas (1 [...] 14)?

Comment: Tipo, quando eu colocar certinho, vai aparecer 85 links e eu preciso limitar a 10 por exemplo senão vai ficar horrível essa quantidade gigante de links.

Comment: Acredito que a resposta do @KaduAmaral seja o que você quer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

É fácil fazer isso.

Primeiro defina um limite de links a ser exibido antes e depois:

```
$lim = 3;
```

Então defina o início da exibição de acordo com a página atual e o limite:

```
$inicio = ((($pg - $lim) > 1) ? $pg - $lim : 1);
```

<sub>Se a subtração for maior que 1, inicie por ela, senão a partir de 1.</sub>

Então defina o limite final:

```
$fim = ((($pg+$lim) < $qtdPag) ? $pg+$lim : $qtdPag);
```

<sub>Se a soma for menor que a quantidade final, então finalize com ela, senão com a quantidade final.</sub>

E pra finalizar, defina o *loop* iniciando e terminando com essas regras:

```
if($qtdPag > 1 && $pg <= $qtdPag){
   for($i = $inicio; $i <= $fim; $i++){

      if($i == $pg){
         echo "<li><a class='ativo'>".$i."</a></li>";
      } else {
        echo "<li><a href='busca?pg=$i'>".$i."</a></li>";
      }

   }
}
```

Caso o usuário esteja na página 5, os links que serão exibidos são:

```
[2] [3] [4] 5 [6] [7] [8]
```

Comment: Me atende perfeitamente. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. É incrível como essa classe de profissionais é unida para ajudar uns aos outros. Obrigado mais uma vez!!!