# Como posso fazer a paginação destes resultados?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, paginação

Fiz uma SQL para filtrar resultados conforme os parâmetros desejados que resultou na seguinte instrução:

```
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM imovel ".trim($where, ' AND '));
```

Visto que eu usei PDO para montar a `$query` tenho que fazer a paginação de resultados em `PDO` ou posso faze-lá em `MySQL`?

Exemplo de resultado da `$query`:

```
SELECT * FROM imovel WHERE 1=1 AND CATEGORIA IN ('CASA') AND DORMITORIO IN (2)
```

Tenho que executar também a paginação, o número das páginas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Recomendo não montar as querys do modo como você está fazendo. Pesquise por PreparedStatements. Quanto a paginacao, nao entendi muito bem sua pergunta. Oque exatamente vc ja tentou?

Comment: Para fazer uma paginação, utilize a opção LIMIT do MySQL, ele tem dois argumentos. Dê uma pesquisada...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A grosso modo, *PDO* é só uma função que vai mandar sua instrução *SQL* para o banco de dados *MySQL*.

E a paginação é feita no MySQL, ou você também pode fazer via programação...

Fica um pequeno exemplo:

```
<?php

   $page = ((isset($_GET['page']) && intval($_GET['page']) > 1)? intval($_GET['page']) : 1) - 1;

   $limite = 15; // limite de registros por página

   $atual = $page*$limite; // Pula a quantidade de registros até os da página atual

   $limit = " LIMIT {$atual}, {$limite}";

   // Registros limitados
   $query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM imovel ".trim($where, ' AND ').$limit); 

   // Todos os Registros para criar as página
   $total = $pdo->query("SELECT count(id) as total FROM imovel ".trim($where, ' AND ')); 

   $qtdtotal = $total['total']; // Pegue a quantidade total
   $qtdpage = ceil($qtdtotal/$limite); // Quantidade de páginas

  // Criando os links
  for ($i = 1; $i<$qtdpage; $i++){

     echo '<a href="paginacao.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a><br>';

  }
```

Então, pra efeitos de programação, nesse caso, não tem muita diferença se você está usando `PDO`, `mysql_*` ou `mysqli::*`.

Alguns *links* sobre paginação:

> [MySQL Paginação de Registros](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/375/mysql-paginacao-de-registros.aspx)
>   [Entendendo a Paginação de Registros no MySQL](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/entendendo-a-paginacao-de-registros-no-mysql/)
>   [Como limitar a quantidade de páginas mostradas numa paginação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34850/como-limitar-a-quantidade-de-p%C3%A1ginas-mostradas-numa-pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o/34854#34854)

Comment: Como vou manter a `SQL` buscada com variáveis do tipo `$_POST`?

Comment: Limitando a quantidade de registros consultados a `12` e tendo todas as variáveis em `$_POST` eu como obter os próximos resultados.

Comment: No final da listagem você coloca os links das demais páginas da paginação, você pode fazer uma consulta da quantidade de todos os registros e fazer um cálculo dividindo pela quantidade a ser exibida em cada página, assim terá o número de páginas geradas...

Comment: Tente fazer ai, e se não estiver conseguindo poste seu código para que possamos ajuda-lo.

Comment: É que o código que você me prôpos justamente limita a quantidade de registros a serem buscados ai eu não consigo o total de registros para usar para paginação.

Comment: Isso, daí no caso é só você fazer outra consulta, sem o LIMIT

Comment: Adicionado exemplo...

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in /home/axitech/www/imo/wp-content/themes/colnaghi/modulos/resultado_busca.php on line 47 (`$qtdtotal = $total['total'];`)

Comment: O código que eu coloquei ali é só de exemplo, você tem que adapta-lo a sua realidade, você tem uma coluna chamada `id`? Se não, coloque o campo chave da sua tabela, ou apenas `*`, assim `count(*) as total`. Você tem que receber esses dados da mesma forma que você recebe os outros.