# SELECT para obter muitas linhas no PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, paginação

Sou iniciante em PHP e MySQL e preciso saber o que faço para obter todos os usuários cadastrados em um banco de dados quando o número de usuários chegar em milhares?

Cadastrei 300 mil usuários em meu banco de dados e gostaria de uma maneira de obter todos eles sem causarem "Allowed memory size" no PHP. Como trazer os resultados por pedaços?

Comment: Paginação[.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/251066/18246)

Comment: Vc precisa de todos os dados de uma vez? para algum relatorio? ou para exibição ? se for exibição usa paginação... para o problema de memoria vc pode aumentar no php.ini ou até com a função ini_set('memory_limit', '64M') por exemplo.

Comment: [Como posso fazer a paginação destes resultados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35516/91)

Comment: Precisa mesmo trazer todos os dados desses usuários? Uma boa prática é trazer somente o necessário. Evitando o "select * from". 
Agora 300 mil usuários é realmente grande demais em minha opinião para um programa em PHP.
1ª dica: Faça uma procedure na base para processar no banco de dados (Não é legal mais tira o peso do PHP)
2ª dica: Troque de linguagem para uma que não acabe com a memória do servidor e seja mais robusta como o C#