# Paginação de produtos com PDO

Tags: php, paginação

Preciso criar uma paginação para o meu banco de dados com 180 produtos, só que as imagens sem paginação aparecem todas as 180 uma do lado da outra, como posso fazer para limitar as imagens 10 por pagina lado a lado?

Eis o meu código:

```
<?php
echo'<table width="88%" height="10" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>';
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=loja", "root", "");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `produtos` ORDER BY `id` ASC ");
$stmt->execute( );
$linha = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($linha = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo'<br>';
    echo'<p><td align=center ><h2><font size="5" face="Trebuchet MS">'.$linha['nome'].'</font></font></p></h2>';
    echo "<div align=center ><img src='".$linha['foto']."' width='160' height='160' border='0'></p>";
    echo '<a href="carrinho.php?acao=add&id='.$linha['id'].'"><button type="button" name="" value="" class="quero">Eu Quero!</button>';
}
echo "</tr></table>";
?>
```

Comment: Relacionado: [Como limitar a quantidade de páginas mostradas numa paginação?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34854/91)

Answer (score 0):

Para limitar a quantidade de registros duma consulta, utilize a cláusula [LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

```
SELECT * FROM `produtos` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: pois eu gostaria de criar uma paginação com os links para a pagina tipo anterior e proximo.

Comment: Dê uma lida no link que o rray comentou na sua pergunta.

Comment: vou testar aqui rray, vlw pela ajuda.

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda , consegui! muito obrigado!